# Is It possible to call angularjs app by post request?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

Is it possible to open angular application from another application as widget or as post request? (I did it as get request)

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense... an angular "application" means you have a web page that loads a JS script that executes a function on dom ready to start parsing the page and looking for an ng-app directive, when one is found the angular bootstrap script then tries to configure/run/load that module and any dependencies... not clear what you're asking everything in angular runs in the context of the javascript engine and is sandboxed to the window/tab.

Comment: I have 2 applications one of them has widget where I called second application by some link like  *url?parap=param1&* it works fine, my question is, is it possible run the application by some post request instead of following link?

Comment: this makes no sense still... POST is an http verb/method used when submitting data to a server, GET is another http verb/method for requesting data from a server, neither of these verbs/methods has anything to do with angular applications.  I think you are confusing things by talking about "applications" are you talking about states?

Comment: Yes, but angular application is hosted by some server(node for example), wich handle request like localhost:4200, so yes you are right i mean state!

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Your Angular app is running in a javascript context client side.
The only way to do what you described will be to handle the POST request with a backend and display the view that contains your angular app.

Comment: The problem is that, I have route for some of my component with parameters, but happened that I got to big parameter, so is it possible to navigate to this components by post request?

Comment: If you want to handle POST requests whatever the reason is, you will need to implement a backend.